# Is there a way to map a numpy array to a certain dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a DataFrame, let's say:

```py
#d = {'col1': [1, 2, 3], 'col2': [3, 4, 5]} // that's what the data might look like
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

and I have a np array with `[0, 2]`.

Now I want to add a column to the DataFrame, where there is a 1, when the index of the row is in the np array, otherwise a 0.

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html) with cast mask to integers:

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2, 3], 'col2': [3, 4, 5]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

a = np.array([0, 2])

df['new'] = df.index.isin(a).astype(int)
#alternative
#df['new'] = np.in1d(df.index, a).astype(int)
```

Or use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['new'] = np.where(df.index.isin(a), 1, 0)
#alternative
#df['new'] = np.where(np.in1d(df.index, a), 1, 0)

print (df)
   col1  col2  new
0     1     3    1
1     2     4    0
2     3     5    1
```